# How to contribute a Label to an Eclipse RCP 3.X Application status-bar?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Im working on a new eclipse bundle (Eclipse RCP Legacy mixed mode) that must contribute some information to our applications status-bar (that one on right bottom corner).

The class that extends ActionBarAdvisor is in another bundle and cant be edited by me. So just an overriding of `protected void fillStatusLine(IStatusLineManager statusLine)` in that class is not an option for me.

I need to contribute directly to the status-bar out of my new bundle. Me new bundle has a .e4xmi file (remember my rcp application bundle dont have any .e4xmi file ) and I want to create a model fragment in my bundle and contribute to the status bar. Here my problem starts, I dont know what to type in into Extended Element-ID, Feature Name and so on...

Comment: Your RCP will be using the 'LegacyIDE.e4xmi' in org.eclipse.ui.workbench as the main application model.

Comment: Sry I dont understand. I need to access the global status bar in my new bundle.

Comment: If your RCP application bundle does not use an Application.e4xmi then the LegacyIDE.e4xmi provided by Eclipse is used. You will have to look in that, but I am not sure you can do this in a fragment e4xmi file as most of the status line is created dynamically.

Comment: We dont  have any  LegacyIDE.e4xmi in entire workspace

Comment: It is in the Eclipse plugins. org.eclipse.platform or org.eclipse.ui.workbench

Comment: Ok found that, and what todo with LegacyIDE.e4xmi now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197992/discussion-between-tristate-and-greg-449).